# searching for a word in expect output

Tags: linux, parsing, output, expect

I have an expect command

```
expect "~]#" { send "virsh list --all\r"}
```

and the output would be

```
[root@lht1oneems-unit0 ~]# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 399   lht1duplexvm-0                 running
 -     rhelvm                         shut off
```

I want to use $expect_out(buffer) and have an if statement to do something if it finds running and do something else if not. 
how can I parse into the result of $expect_out(buffer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```tcl
expect "~]#"
send "virsh list --all\r"

# I assume another prompt follows this
expect "~]#"

if { [regexp {running} $expect_out(buffer)] } {
    do-something-for-running-process
} else {
    do-something-for-no-running-process
}
```

You could also do

```
if {[string first "running" $expect_out(buffer)] >= 0} {
```